# GPO option for "Show Desktop Icons"?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

Is there a GPO setting (Server 2008 R2 domain) that we can use to set the following desktop property?

[image: View - Show Desktop Icons]

View > Show Desktop Icons

Comment: Your screenshot is so perfect and beautiful!

Comment: @Daniel Yeahhhh I re-wrote his question and edited that screenshot in. I stole the screenshot by doing a google image search. The original question was a bit of a mess (see the edit history)

Comment: I noticed that the answer given was to HIDE icons, but the questions asked was HOW TO SHOW icons. I want every user to have some typical icons on the desktop (NOT JUST RECYCLE BIN). I am just learning Group Policy, so I have not yet figured out how to do this. should be easier than this!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there is an option in GPO.

[image: Hide desktop icons]

Do realize that users can still add or create shortcuts or items on their desktops. You can also prohibit this if needed.

If you want to do it using the registry, you can do it in

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\HideIcons
```

you can still deploy this using GPO. You can find this under **computer configuration > prefrences > Windows settings** and add there the registry you want to create.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any GPO policy on its own that will do this, but the registry key to do this is

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\HideIcons
```

Set to `1` to hide the icons. If you change the registry directly you'll need to log off and back on to affect the change.

Comment: thank you good sir i would upvote your answer if i can but i don't have 15 reputation yet haha

Comment: You can always vote on answers to your own questions, but it's all good.

Comment: The answer by saeed is a better answer. You should give them the check mark.

Comment: Also, if there was *not* a specific policy to do this, you could always add this reg key to the gpo.